# Vagrant crashes depending on physical network

Tags: networking, npm, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a virtual machine I manage using Vagrant. When provisioning, I get some updates for the system (Ubuntu) using `apt-get`, install Node.js using `nvm`, and then run `npm install` for various modules. Now strange things happen:

If I try to create and provision the VM in physical network A (at one place), provisioning fails. Either creation already fails and Vagrant tells me that the machine went to an invalid state, or the VM crashes when npm starts to do its work.

If I try to do the exactly same thing on physical network B (at another place), everything is fine.

As the only difference between the two places (I can think of) is the physical network, I wonder how this can happen. I have tried it with two different MacBooks, one running Mavericks, the other running Mountain Lion. The effect happens on *both* and also when using different Vagrant / VirtualBox versions, so apparently it's actually a problem of the environment.

Any idea what might cause issues like that?

Comment: I just saw exactly the same behaviour on my MacBook running OS 10.8.5. While `vagrant up` works at home connected to my wifi, it gives this error message when launching a VM while connected to the wifi at work: _The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to boot. (...) The machine is in the 'aborted' state._ I even tried several VirtualBox and Vagrant versions, but the problem stayed.

Comment: Do you have any idea what causes this issue? What's your IP range at both networks? IPv4 vs IPv6? …?

Comment: IP4 on both, the IP ranges are the same and the vendor of the wifi access points are the same.

Comment: Ultra-strange. For me, it's at least two entirely different network configurations, but this *really* is strange :-(

Comment: As soon as I'm back in our office, I'll do some experiments. E.g. I'll try vagrant with wifi switched off and/or connected to our ethernet LAN. Yesterday I had no idea that network environment could cause that strange behaviour. I'd have tested it.

Comment: Great :-) … perhaps we find it out, and can submit an issue for Vagrant and / or VirtualBox. If you want to discuss details, feel free to contact me via email (webmaster@goloroden.de).

Comment: I had the opportunity to do some tests today. In my home office, it worked. Been at a client's office, while connected to their wifi, it worked, too. At our headquarter, connected to our wifi, it didn't work. Canceling wifi on my Macbook, it worked. Connected my Macbook to the ethernet-based LAN, it also worked. That means: It works in most circumstances, but not while connected to our office's wifi. Strange.

Comment: Did you figure out what this issue was? I'm having it now.
If I turn wifi off, the VM boots. I don't have ethernet setup at home so can't test with that.

os x 10.9 & virtualbox 4.3.4

Comment: ... So I looked through the config of the vm with this issue & with another vm that works. The bung one had only 12mb video ram & the working one 16mb. change the bung one to 16 & seems to be working now. The box in question is this one: http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box

Comment: Didn't work for me :-/. Tried 16, 128 and 256 MBytes, and none of them helped avoid the aborted VM.

Comment: @z80crew Did you test it already with Vagrant 1.4.0? I'll have to wait until next weekend, but I'd be interested if 1.4.0 changes anything for you?

Comment: No, it's version 1.3.5 for me so far.

Comment: Checked it today, and it still happens for me with 1.4.0 :-/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this thread is a bit older, but I've got the same problem and I found a solution.

Here is a official issue and a solution https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2786

There are issues related "NAT Networking" and massive DNS querys. I had several `npm install` running in my provisioner.

My solution, as described at the official github issue:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'on']
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes. Yes. YES! Thank you so much for your answer! This finally helped me before I was getting crazy!