# Strange Vagrant error message: 'Unable to create a host network interface'

Tags: networking, vagrant

I have a Vagrant machine based on VirtualBox that has some problems (see [Vagrant crashes depending on physical network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194128/vagrant-crashes-depending-on-physical-network)). Now I tried running it on another piece of hardware (with OS X Mavericks), and got the following error message:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Unable to create a host network interface
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component Host,
interface IHost, callee nsISupports
Context: "CreateHostOnlyNetworkInterface (hif.asOutParam(),
progress.asOutParam())" at line 64 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

What does this mean?

For the error to appear I run

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
```

… and then it crashes. Any ideas?

Oh, by the way: It's Vagrant 1.3.5 and VirtualBox 4.1.18.

Comment: crash might mean that there is a bug in virtualbox. 4.1.18 is quite old. Can you upgrade?

Comment: Yes, I'll upgrade and try again…

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

worked for me, see https://coderwall.com/p/ydma0q

Comment: Worked for me too, even though I'm running pretty old VB as well, 4.1.20r80170.

Answer (score 2):

The popular answer seems to be `modprobe vboxnetadp` (for Linux) or `/Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart` (for Mac).

However, the fix for me was to add myself to the `vboxusers` group and relogin.

Comment: I think you should only mention what worked for you, rather than what didn't, it led to negative votes on your comment it seems. I do agree with you however: adding myself to vboxusers (then going via su to relogin without logging out) fixed this error message for me as well (on linux).